# Example of function $u\in C^{\infty}(R)$ with $u(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $u(x)=1$ for $x>1$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have tried a function $f(x)$ to be as $e^{-\frac {1}{x^{2}}}$, then it doesnot satisfy the given condition, i have been stucked up here, then what could be the function to satisfy the given condition?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: first construct a $C^{\infty}$ function $f(x)$ such that $f=0$ for $x<0$ and $x>1$, and such that 
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\;dx=\int_{0}^1f(x)\;dx=1$. Then define
$$ u(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\;dt$$

Comment: I have dealt with the exponential function but didnt work, what do you think could be the right choice?

Comment: In other words, think of $u(x)$ as the cumulative distribution function of a probability density $f(x)$.

Comment: A variant of $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ will work. You want the function $f(x)$ to be rapidly decaying to zero as $x\to0$ and $x\to 1$.

Comment: How could it be constructed to satisfy the integral as mentioned in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in (0,1)$ let  $f(x)=g(x) h(x)$ where $g(x)=e\cdot \exp (-1/x)$ and $h(x)= 1-\exp (-1/(1-x))$ .

Use the product rule for the $n$th derivative of $g(x)h(x)$ to confirm that $f^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(1)=0$ for all $n>0.$